# How to check if GPS is connected and the position updated

Tags: android, gps, android-location

The GPS needs  to be connected to a GPS satellite to track the position in realtime.
The problem is that sometimes it could lose the connection and if I invoke

```
    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

I get the last known location that may differ from actual position.
How to check if GPS is connected and the position updated before invoke / use `getLastKnownLocation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the [`GpsStatus.Listener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html) interface on your `Activity` or `Service`:

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements GpsStatus.Listener
{

   private LocationManager locationManager;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savdedInstanceState)
       ....
       ....
       locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
       locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) 
   {

      switch (event) 
      {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
        break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:  
        /* This is when GPS is activated; add code here for how you want the application to react. */                        
        break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
        break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement **GpsStatus.Listener** for this.

for example,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements GpsStatus.Listener
{
         ...
         ...
         ...
         // add listener into locationManager
        locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);

       @Override
       public void onGpsStatusChanged(int) 
       {

          switch (event) 
         {
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:   // this means you  found GPS Co-ordinates                          
            break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            break;
          }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sir,
I also know this is also a great problem.
There is no way to check status if the position is updated or not.

However, you can use `GpsStatus.Listener`.

It returns the `getLastKnownLocation`, previous cached data.
Best way is to not use `getLastKnownLocation`, and Simply get the live GPS location.